# Why is there no access to the port 0xCF8?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, pci

I use ubuntu as an OS in Virtual Box(virtual machine). And my goal is to list all the pci devices that can be found in the system using c++ code. Here is a part of it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/io.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NOT_SPECIFIED "Not specified"

int main()
{
    int i, busid, devid;
    FILE * file = fopen("Pcibits.txt", "w+");
    for (busid = 0; busid < 256; busid++)
    {
        for (devid = 0; devid < 32; devid++)
        {
            unsigned int recvp, ven_id, dev_id, clid;
            unsigned int sendp =  (busid << 16) | (devid << 11) | ((unsigned int)0x80000000);
            outl(sendp, 0x0CF8);
            recvp = inl(0x0CFC);
            char* str = new char[32];
            sprintf(str, "%d", recvp);
            fwrite(str, sizeof(char), sizeof(str)/sizeof(char), file);
            fclose(file);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}`
```

But using gdb I struggle with the error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py", line 63, in <module>
    from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
ImportError: No module named 'libstdcxx'

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040075a in outl (__value=2256549650, __port=3320)
    at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/io.h:125
125   __asm__ __volatile__ ("outl %0,%w1": :"a" (__value), "Nd" (__port));
```

What is wrong with it? As I realize the program fails on the outl-step.
Please help!)

Comment: If you have Ubuntu as an operating system, why are you trying to work around the OS by accessing the hardware directly, instead of *[using the features of the operating system](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci)*?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Ubuntu reference for these types of functions](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man2/inw.2.html).

> You use ioperm(2) or alternatively iopl(2) to tell the kernel to 
>   allow    the  user  space  application  to  access  the  I/O  ports in
>   question.    **Failure to do this will cause the application to receive**
>   **a segmentation    fault**.

(Emphasis mine)

So you have to set the proper permission for your program to prevent the segmentation fault.

See more on how to set the low level port access permissions [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man2/ioperm.2.html)